# Manasa and Prime game (Hackerrank)

Tags: game-theory

I need help in solving this question -

Manasa loves the NIM Game, but having played the same game so many times, she gets bored one day. So she wants to change the rules of the game. As she loves prime numbers, she makes a new rule: any player can remove only prime number of balls from a bucket. But there are infinite prime numbers. So to keep the game simple, a player can remove only x number of balls from a bucket, where x belongs to the set S.
S={2,3,5,7,11,13}
Now whole game can be described as follows: 
Given N number of buckets and kth bucket having Ak number of balls, a player can choose a bucket and remove x number of balls from that bucket where x belongs to S. Manasa plays the first move against Sandy. Who will win if both of them play optimally?

Comment: What is the victory condition? Having the most balls? (Also, hackerrank looks like a place where companies give out coding challenges. If you're taking a challenge from one of them, you shouldn't be asking for help solving it.)

Comment: The player who removes the last ball wins. I am solving this question just for practice and I don't know much about game theory.

Answer (score 0):

following code solves it perfectly:

```
from itertools import imap
import operator

def mapg(N, A):
  return 0 != reduce(operator.xor, (a%9//2 for a in A), 0)

for _ in xrange(input()):
  N = input()
  A = map(int, raw_input().split())
  print "Manasa" if mapg(N, A) else "Sandy"
```

Answer (score 0):

java solution:

```
import java.io.*;  
import java.util.*;  
import java.text.*;  
import java.math.*;  
import java.util.regex.*;  

public class Solution {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        int t = ni();  
        for(int i=0; i<t; i++){  
            System.out.println(solve());  
        }  
    }  

    public static int[] values = new int[]{0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4};  
    public static String solve(){  
        int n = ni();  
        long ak;  
        long nimber = 0; //or grundy number  
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++){  
            ak = nl();  
            nimber ^= values[(int) (ak % values.length)];
        }  
        if(nimber > 0) return "Manasa";  
        return "Sandy";  
    }  

    public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);  
    public static int ni(){  
        return sc.nextInt();  
    }  
    public static long nl(){  
        return sc.nextLong();  
    }  
}
```

Analysis from [this blog](http://traceformula.blogspot.com/2015/12/hackerrank-manasa-and-prime-game.html).